# iphone :before not triggering parent :hover event

Tags: ios, css, pseudo-element

I have created a CSS drop-down menu, for a mobile theme, that starts off collapsed and has a `:before` element with the word 'Menu' on it. The idea being when the user hovers/clicks/touches the menu "button" it expands and shows the rest of the menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/X4UxP/

This works on desktop browsers, android default browser and android chrome, but does not work on iPhone. I am aware there is a click event delegation issue on the iPhone, however the `:hover` event is still obeyed, which leads me to think there is an issue with the `:hover`  event on the `:before` element not bubbling up correctly.

Is this the issue? Is there a CSS fix for this? Is there a javascript fix for this (I would prefer not to use javascript unless absolutely necessary)?

Comment: Much of `:hover` behavior on iOS is a result of [compatibility measures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188558/what-is-the-default-way-an-ios-device-handles-the-hover-pseudo-class/17188802#17188802). In general, mouse events and the `:hover` pseudo-class are not reliably supported on iOS, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a "bad idea" to use `:hover` pseudo class when it comes to touch screen devices. Mainly because behaviour may be "unexpected" and won't be "future proof".

The "solution" posted by AaronAsAChimp works, because it uses a **clickable** element (here an `a` element), which is mandatory for iOS to trigger the event (see: [**Handling Events**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1)).

But it also has a major drawback in usability, because you cannot close the menu other than using the back button!

So my advice would be:
Always use the `:target` pseudo class instead of `:hover` for your respective (pure) CSS solution.

And use a Javascript solution in case JS is available. This makes the whole event handling much easier for you, and much more comfortable for your visitors!

And about over 98% of all visitors have JS enabled.

I would even say that Responsive Web Design without Javascript support is almost impossible nowadays - at least a "nightmare".

Comment: Good find Netsurfer, I didn't realize Apple had gotten around to documenting that. In regards to `:target` there are some problems. It's not supported in IE <= 8, which may or may not be an issue. It contributes URL pollution-- each menu item will have a unique URL, (not to be confused with the page it links to). This is bad for SEO. And lastly, just because something *can* be done with JavaScript doesn't mean that it *should*. Its about the right tool for the job. :)

Comment: @AaronAsAChimp About your concerns of browser support: Without JS IE <= 8 do not support HTML5 (tags) anyway. And with EOL of XP it is questionable if one still needs to support IE 8? About the `:target` pseudo class: There are only **two** `a` elements needed which have a href like "#menu" (for opening the menu) and "#" (for closing). And as these are anchor tags, how should they be bad for SEO!? And about your last point: Correct, but imho in this case it is the other way round: Just because something can be done with CSS doesn't mean that it should. Use progressive enhancement by using JS.

Comment: Firstly, this is a good discussion and I really enjoy it. :) The OP, or anyone else who sees this thread, may not have a choice of whether or not to support IE8. Tags are just tags, HTML5 only standardized them. Old IE's requires a small fix (html5shiv) to make the default styling work but its still supported. CSS is almost always simpler and faster than JS. Maybe the situations you're in merit using JS, maybe the OP's don't. I don't know, I'm just a random guy on the internet. :) Congrats on the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that iOS devices are touch devices not pointer devices. This causes problems when translating touch events to pointer events, like hover.

iOS uses a heuristic to determine what should receive pointer events. The one you are concerned with is; An element must be an interactive element (like a link or button). The :before pseudo-element doesn't count as interactive.

What should you do? Add an element to your list for the menu button.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu</a>
</li>
```

Then change "ul:before" to "ul .menu-button" in your css.

```
ul .menu-button {
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
```